# Linking UDP IpEndPoints and TCP Sockets?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, udp

I have a server that communicates with clients using both TCP and UDP protocols. I have a list of `Socket`s for TCP communication, and a list of `IpEndPoint`s for UDP communication. If I received a UDP packet, how do I find the TCP `Socket` which is in the `Socket`s `List` and belongs to the same client from the client's `IpEndPoint`? If I received a TCP packet, how do I find the `IpEndPoint` which is in the `IpEndPoint`s `List` and belongs to same the client from the client's `Socket`??
I tried checking if `Socket.LocalEndPoint` is equal to each `IpEndPoint` in my list and vise versa, but this won't work if two instances of the program are run on the same computer simultaneously.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try RemoteEndPoint?

Comment: Yes, didn't work too.

Comment: What IP are you getting?  Are any of them correct?